# Associativity with bounded variation

Tags: martingales, bounded-variation

Lets assume we have a semimartingale S and a martingale Z. In my lecture notes I have an equality I don't really understand

$$-\frac{1}{Z_t}d\langle S,Z\rangle_t = -d\langle S, \int_0^° \frac{dZ}{Z}\rangle _t$$

where $\langle , \rangle$ denotes the bounded variation and $d$ just the differential.

Can anyone explain to me what theorem or trick is used? It looks for me like the associativity of a stochastic integral but we have a bounded variation term and also no integral in front of the left side.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's a famous characterization of stochastic integral. Maybe you could find it in your textbook.

Comment: Are you referring to the property that $<\int a_u dZ_u> = \int a^2_u d<Z>_u$? But it is not clear for me how this is helping me since in the second equation you have on both sides integrals.

Comment: Not exactly. I was referring to $d\langle X, I^M(Y)\rangle=Yd\langle X,M\rangle$, which is a characteristic property of stochastic integral. You may find a proof in Karatzas & Shreve, _Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus_.

Comment: Sorry but I have to ask again. I think I found the theorem you meant. It is Lemma 2.16 of the following link http://www.math.cmu.edu/~omostovy/papers_not_mine/ProbAndStochProcesses/Ioannis%20Karatzas,%20Steven%20E.%20Shreve%20Brownian%20Motion%20and%20Stochastic%20Calculus,%202nd%20Edition%20%201996.pdf. My question is where did the integral go? How did it vanish?

Comment: The integral vanishes in a natural way, since you are taking differentials. You may recall that in ordinary calculus, we have $d\int_0^t f(s)ds=f(t)dt$.

Comment: Ah ok thank you!